# Does the iPad 1 have voice control?

Tags: ipad, voice-control

I have the iPad 1, and I'd like to use Voice Control on it. However, I can't seem to bring it up the normal way (holding down the home button). Does the iPad 1 have Voice Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only devices with Voice Control of any form, whether pre-iOS 5 "Voice Command" or iOS 5+ "Siri", is an iPhone 3GS or later, and the 4th Generation iPod touch.

All iPhones since the 3GS and iOS 3 (IIRC) have Voice Command. iPhone 4/4S' on iOS 5 or later have Siri, unless disabled then Voice Command is used instead.

iPod touches do not have Siri, though the fourth generation does have Voice Command. No iPad has Voice Command nor Siri. This is true of all models and iOS versions as of this writing.

Comment: Actually, the 4th generation iPod touch *has* Voice Control. I don't know about anything earlier.

Comment: Huh, I don't recall hearing about that. But, nevertheless, modified to suit.

Comment: Also, the answer is outdated by now.

Answer (score 3):

No, voice control is not native to iPad 1.

Comment: The iPad 2 does not either. Not part of the question, but related/relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The 3th gen iPod touch had voice control, you just have to have headphones with a remote and mic.

Comment: Can this be expanded to explain how an iPod hardware would relate to the iPad? Something's missing in this answer to my eye.